# Monodroid - Handling events on child Views of reused ListView rows

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

Android's ListView reuses rows that have been scrolled out of view.
But, that seems to be a problem when handling events on a row's child Views in C#.

An accepted way of adding event handlers in Java is to explicitly **set** a handler like so:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.pic);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println(position);
    }  
});
```

Documents on Xamarin's site encourage developers to use C#'s **add** event listener pattern which doesn't play nice with reused rows:

```
ImageView img = row.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.pic);
img.Click += (sender, e) => {
    Console.WriteLine(position);
};
```

---

The Java pattern above which **sets** an event handler is well suited for row reuse while the C# pattern beneath it which **adds** an event handler causes handlers to pile up on child Views of the reused rows.

The code below shows my **`GetView`** method from a custom BaseAdapter I wrote.

```
public override Android.Views.View GetView (int position,
                                            View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;

    //TODO: solve event listener bug. (reused rows retain events).
    if (row == null) {
        row = LayoutInflater.From (userListContext)
                .Inflate (Resource.Layout.UserListUser, null, false);
    }

    ImageView profilePic = row.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.profilePic);

    //if(profilePic.Clickable) { /** kill click handlers? **/ }
    profilePic.Click += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.PutString("id", UserList[position].id);

        Intent intent = new Intent(userListContext, typeof(ProfileActivity));
        intent.PutExtras(extras);
        postListContext.StartActivity(intent);
    };

    return row;
}
```

The problem is, when a row is reused, the `profilePic` view still has the original "click" handler attached.

Is there a way to (a) wipe out `profilePic.Click` or (b) use the Android's `profilePic.SetOnClickListener` Java pattern with anonymous functions?

Or, is there a better pattern to use where the "click" handler can still access the proper value of `position`?

Answer (score 3):

> Or, is there a better pattern to use where the "click" handler can
>   still access the proper value of position?

Use `setTag/getTag` method to get right position of clicked row inside Click method of `ImageView` click listener:

```
profilePic.SetTag(Resource.Id.profilePic, position);
profilePic.Click += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        int clickedPos = (int)(((Button)sender).GetTag (Resource.Id.profilePic));
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.PutString("id", UserList[clickedPos].id);
        ......
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. Is there a solution that could retain access to other things in the scope of my GetView function?

Comment: @MicronXD: ok try it.what you want to access in scope of my GetView ?

Comment: @MicronXD: also my suggestion is use `ViewHolder Pattern` for good ListView performance and avoid to recreate views again which is already created see following like [Xamarin Android - deleting item from ListView deletes TWO items](http://quabr.com/28474874/xamarin-android-deleting-item-from-listview-deletes-two-items) probably more helpful

Comment: This is the correct way to do it but keep in mind this adds a new anonymous event handler that can't be deregistered every time the row gets reused. Shift the delegate logic into a separate method and deregister then re-register it every time the `GetView` is called.

Answer (score 1):

First +1 for the ViewHolder pattern mention/suggestion. You are on the right track @MicronXD however I want to encourage you to use the ViewHolder pattern, it makes good utilization of view re-usages of your rows.

Then next you need to create a method in your Activity that actually does the job of starting another Activity, and this new method should accept an int which is the ID of the object that has the image your are interested in or you can pass in the whole object. So for example if you are instantiating your custom adapter from MainActivity then you can create a method called public void OnThumbnailClicked(int id)

Then each time an image is clicked, you get the id of the object that was clicked and call the method like so: ( I have used a customer example)

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            CustomerHolder holder = null;
            var view = convertView;

            if (view == null)
            {
                view = Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomRow, null);

                holder = new CustomerHolder();
                holder.Name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewName);
                holder.Email = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewEmail);
                holder.Phone = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewPhone);
                holder.Image = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageViewThumbail);

                view.Tag = holder;
            }
            else
            {
                    holder = view.Tag as CustomerHolder;
            }

            //At this point the holder holds reference to your view objects, whether they are 
            //recycled or created new. 
            //Next then you need to populate the views with the Customer info

            var Customer = Customers[position];
            holder.Name.Text = Customer.Name;
            holder.Email.Text = CustomerHolder.Email;
            holder.Phone.Text = Customer.Phone;
            holder.Image.SetImageResource = (Resource.Drawable.defaulthumbnail);
            holder.Image.Clickable = true;
            holder.Image.Click += (o, e) =>
            {
                   var myActivity = (MainActivity)Context;
                   myActivity.OnThumbnailclicked((Customer[position).id);

            };
            return view;
        }

       private class CustomerHolder : Java.Lang.Object
        {
            public TextView Name { get; set; }
            public TextView Email { get; set; }
            public TextView Phone { get; set; }
            public ImageView Thumbnail { get; set; }                
        }        

}
```